# Error invoking a formula

Tags: excel

I'm trying to invoke following formula in one of the cells in my excel worksheet.But I'm getting an error 
as Invalid formula.

```
=IF(myfunction("EUR CURNCY","INVERSE_QUOTED") ='Y', myfunction("EUR CURNCY","LAST_PRICE"),1)
```

Note:myFunction is my custom function.I believe the problem is above is the syntax.

Could you advise please?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you also share the code for `myfunction` and sample data?

Comment: How are we supposed to troubleshoot a custom function in which you haven't exposed any of the code?

Comment: Thanks John.That was the issue.It works for me now!!!

Comment: By any chance -- are you a Python programmer? Recently I have done much more Python than VBA and find as a side effect that I sometimes use single-quoted string literals in VBA by accident. Sometime it is hard to keep the syntactic details of various languages straight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A single quoted string is not a valid string literal.

Replace

```
=IF(myfunction("EUR CURNCY","INVERSE_QUOTED") ='Y', myfunction("EUR CURNCY","LAST_PRICE"),1)
```

by

```
=IF(myfunction("EUR CURNCY","INVERSE_QUOTED") ="Y", myfunction("EUR CURNCY","LAST_PRICE"),1)
```

If that doesn't fix the problem, please post the code for `myfunction`.